# Closest pair of points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

In
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem
we can see that it mentions that is at most 6 points that is closest to the point on the other half, which can be represented as the graph below:
[image]

My question is for point P1 and Point P2, the distance to the red point will exceed sqrt(2)*d, why it is part of the solution? Why it is not at most 4 points that is closest to P rather than at most 6 points? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*P1* and *P2* are not part of the solution, but they have to be examined on the way to the solution, because the algorithm examines all points in the box, and *P1* and *P2* are in the box.

Note that no such point as your *Q* can exist, because by hypothesis the minimum distance between points in the right-hand half of the diagram is *d*.

Edited to add: you seem to think that the Wikipedia article is making a claim like this:

- There may be up to 6 points on the right side of the line that are within a distance *d* of *P*.

This claim would be false. But the article does not make such a claim. Instead, it makes two separate claims, both of which are true:

1. All the points on the right side of the line that are within a distance *d* of *P* are inside the box.
2. There may be up to 6 points in the box.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, if "There may be up to 6 points on the right side of the line that are within a distance d of P." is false, what is the correct number of points? If it is less than 6 points, can we examine say only 5 points?

Comment: I think the maximum number of points in the right-hand half that are within a distance *d* of *P* is actually **three**. But the problem is, how do we arrange to examine those points and only those points? It is fairly easy to build a data structure so that we can efficiently list the points within the box, but what data structure will do the job for the circular segment?

Comment: Yea, thanks for the help, I am not sure whether I could ask a question that is not very related to the question: may I know what software you are using to draw the diagram? That seems pretty nice :)

Comment: Hi Gareth, if I wish draw similar graph in windows 7, do you have any recommended graphic drawing software (like OmniGraffle for Mac)?

Comment: What if we trim down the points in the box to strictly less than d? That way we will only have 3 points in the box that are d away from each other

Answer (score 3):

We are only counting the maximum number of points that can lie in the right d x 2d rectangle. Since any two points are constrained to have a minimum distance of d, we can place at most 6 points in the rectangle while satisfying this constraint, as shown in the figure.

Note that the points on the right side that are within d distance from P should all lie within a circular segment of a circle centered at P and whose radius is d. There can be at most 4 points in this segment. However, finding the number of points within a segment is more complicated than finding the number of points within a rectangle. So we use the rectangle instead and incur an extra cost of having to search for at most 2 additional points.

Comment: No, you cannot have 6 points that are within d distance from P. I have edited the post to make this more clear. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The bound is only important for complexity estimation. Code-wise, you may simply scan up and down within the distance dRmin. The bound here suggest that you'll at most see 6 points in each such scan, making this O(1).